# Using RowReduce in Wolfram-Alpha gives wrong answer

Tags: independence, wolfram-alpha

I tried to check whether the vectors [1,1,1],[4,3,2],[3,1,6] are linearly independent over GF(7).

I used "rowreduce([[1,4,3],[1,3,1],[1,2,6]]) in gf(7)" in Wolfram-Alpha and it told me they're **independent**. However, 3*[4,3,2]+2*[3,1,6]+3*[1,1,1]=0, which implies they're **dependent**.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing.

Would appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you reason that the addition of three positive integers in each of the columns will equal a zero vector?

Comment: @GrahamKemp It's in $\Bbb F_7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper syntax in *Mathematica* is:

`RowReduce[{{1, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 6}}, Modulus -> 7]`

which yields

`{{1, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 0, 0}}`

However, this input is not accepted in WolframAlpha.  What it appears to do is perform the row reduction in $\mathbb Z$, then take the result modulo $7$, which is not what you want.  Interestingly, if you write

`RowReduce[{{1, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, -1}}]`

you do see that the matrix is not full rank.

This is an example of how the natural language processing in WolframAlpha does not always give the intended output:  whereas *Mathematica* provides an unambiguous syntax for specifying a particular expression to be evaluated, not all features of the Wolfram language are implemented as valid inputs in WolframAlpha.  This is intentional, since if it were possible to evaluate arbitrary *Mathematica* code in WolframAlpha, it would eliminate much of the incentive to purchase the software.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Is there a free tool to calculate if a given set of vectors is independent over GF(q)?